# Python TA-Lib abstract API usage

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I've had a look at the module documentation for **TA-Lib** as well as the [abstract-specific guide](http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/abstract.html), yet I am still unclear as to what exactly the **abstract API** can do for me (and how). Specifically, I would like to see a **Python code example** that instantiates a custom indicator which maintains indicator value state and periodically calculates, say, RSI from an individual input value, as opposed to an array of input values.

What I envision is the ability to pass values to an indicator sequentially (as they become available), so for example, instead of maintaining a numpy array of 700 items to calculate RSI on 5 minute candles - every 5 minutes - I wonder if it is possible to pass an abstract indicator function the candle close price, once every 5 minutes, and for it to output the 14-period RSI value calculated from state. This would be better suited to my application which keeps track of 9 different indicator values for 5 different timeframes indefinitely and around the clock.

Whilst numpy arrays are convenient for generating once-off indicator value arrays, a live system with ongoing indicator calculations would be more easily maintained and more memory efficient were the TA-Lib object to maintain indicator state somehow. Is this something the abstract API can do?

If not, I see an **alternative** in having a **rotating deque** (of 14 items - the RSI period) which can serve as input to the abstract indicator. A code example of **custom data** type implementation via TA-Lib abstract would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, an answer with example code is provided at [GitHub](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/43)